# Finding the value of the identifier

Tags: python

Getting the value of the first **id** is obvious. How to get the value of the **second id** in the function ***is*** ?

```
   id(False)
=> 140399586313184
   id(id(False))
=> 140399542553456
   id(False) is id(False)
=> False
```

Python documentation:

```
operator.is_(a, b)
```

Return a is b. Tests object identity.

Operator.is_ (a, b) performs the function *id(False)* two times. The values in the *id(False)* memory are different. I want to know **B** when id is running *id(False) is id(False)*

Comment: The way your question is written it is hard to understand what you want. Try and explain a bit more clearly

Comment: Using `is` in this way is not meaningful.  Do you mean `==` rather than `is` ?

Comment: @cdarke no, I mean  is.  Id (False) == id (False) have the same values. I am interested in the values of id during the execution of is. Because the values in memory are different.

Comment: But that does not compare the values of the id's, it compares the references of the id's, not their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id (False) is id (False)` compares the *references of the id's* that are returned by the `id()` function.  It does not compare the references of `False`.

You can get similar effects with any large integers in python, not just id's.

In the case of the C implementation these are large integers (memory addresses) and their actual value is not useful and are implementation specific.

Whether two integers with the same *value* have the same reference is likewise implementation specific, and not guaranteed.   The C implementation does some optimisation, but only of "small" numbers.  See ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Answer (score 1):

`is` is NOT a valid way of comparing integers (or most types, for that matter).  Both sides of `id(False) is id(False)` produce the same integer *value*, but they are two distinct integer *objects* (since the value is outside of the range where the small integer cache applies).  `is` therefore properly returns False.  If you had compared the values using `==`, the result would have been True.